# How to pass for loop variable value in a class of a anchor tag in PUG template engine?

Tags: javascript, html, pug, pugjs

I am trying to print `<a>` tag 5 times by using **PUG template engine**.

I want my code like it is below. Where I just want two classe **item** and **item-1,2,3** etc.

> **HTML code: desired result**

```
<a class="item item-1" href="#">1  Item</a><br/>
<a class="item item-2" href="#">2  Item</a><br/>
<a class="item item-3" href="#">3  Item</a><br/>
<a class="item item-4" href="#">4  Item</a><br/>
```

I am using this code now which is below and working fine

> **PUG code**

```
- for (var x=1; x < 6; x++)
    a.item.item-(href='#') #{x}  Item
    br
```

Which output in HTML is below and `#{x}` variable to printing fine

```
<a class="item item-" href="#">1  Item</a><br/>
<a class="item item-" href="#">2  Item</a><br/>
<a class="item item-" href="#">3  Item</a><br/>
<a class="item item-" href="#">4  Item</a><br/>
<a class="item item-" href="#">5  Item</a><br/>
```

But when I am using `#{x}` variable like below it is showing error

```
- for (var x=1; x < 6; x++)
    a.item.item-#{x}(href='#') #{x}  Item
    br
```

> **Error**

```
Pug:2:17
    1| - for (var x=1; x < 6; x++)
  > 2|     a.item.item-#{x}(href='#') #{x}  Item
-----------------------^
    3|     br

Unexpected token `interpolation` expected `text`, `interpolated-code`, `code`, `:`, `slash`, `newline` or `eos`
```

I am aware that we use **#** for ID but why it is not printing value of **x** after **`item-`** in class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get your desired result by changing the code as specified in [Pug's documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html):

```
- for (var x=1; x < 6; x++)
    a(class='item item-'+x)(href='#') #{x}  Item
    br
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrqBdY

Comment: it is still not working I am having error again 'Pug:2:17
    1| - for (var x=1; x < 6; x++)
  > 2|     a.item.item-\#{x}(href='#') #{x}  Item
-----------------------^
    3|     br

unexpected text "\#{x}"'

check here https://codepen.io/rhulkashyap/pen/NaNzom

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
- for (var x=1; x < 6; x++)
    a.item(href='#', class="item-#{x}") #{x}  Item
    br
```